# Laravel 5: "class App\Commands\Command not found"

Tags: php, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, I just ran `php artisan make:command doMagicStuff` to create a generic command with a die() statement in the handler.  Whenever I try to `$this->dispatch(new DoMagicStuff()), however, I get:

`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'App\Commands\Command' not found`

If I remove `extends Command` it works, though obviously not correctly.

Is there some reason it can't find App\Commands\Command ?  (Note: In ./app/Commands, there is no Command.php, so that is a hint, though it might live under the vendor directory.  I did a grep for "class Command", but no luck.

Comment: There's one in the vendor directory `Illuminate\Console\Command` you can use. I also encountered this and I suspect it's to encourage the best practice of having your own base Command class in that folder. No idea why it doesn't come with the stock install, though.

Comment: Yes, faced the same issue. Also, there isn't a command directory by default in laravel installation. It is created when running the `make:command` for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you clone the repo from github? The repository there has a `Command.php` with nothing in it, just empty abstract. My projects also have it, so... weird.

Here:  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.0/app/Commands

Whenever you create a command, it is namespaced as `namespace App\Commands;` and you `extends Command`, so it will look in the `App\Commands` dir for a `Command` class, since it exists in the repo, it should exist in your copy too.

Comment: I had this happen to me after I moved a Lumen app over to Laravel.